# How to send XML request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an eye tracker (mirametrix) running as a server in localhost. In order to capture data from this I should send a xml request as given below;

```
SEND:<GET ID="TIME_TICK_FREQUENCY" />
```

I have a web-app running as the client and I need to make a request to this server through that. I wrote the following code but it doesn't seem to send the request properly to the server.

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:4242",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: { 
                data:'<GET ID="TIME_TICK_FREQUENCY" />'

            },

        });
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using jQuery. I presume you included the jQuery file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: "<root><blah><blah></root>", 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success : parse,
    error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
        console.log(xhr.status);          
        console.log(thrownError);
    } 
});
```

I think you need to post it.

Answer (score 1):

this is not plain javascript.. looks more like jquery.. also what do you mean with 'properly'. It's kind sending it, but not really? Aside from that, I see the following problems

- The url is wrong, and although your browser may handle it, your url *should* end with a slash.
- Your xml is invalid. Needs to start with `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.
- If you accessed this script through a different host than 127.0.0.1., or if the script is running on a different port than 4242, this will not work without [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP_access_control) headers on the server.